# Manifest merger failed in android xml file

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, upgrade

[image]I suddenly received the following error message. It is already added to the receiver, service, and activity wherever it is needed. I still get the same error and get stuck there badly

> <receiver#com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver>.
> App targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit
> value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an
> intent filter defined. See
> https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported
> for details.

Here is my manifest file

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.test.app"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

> 

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

-->
 -->

      
        
            
            
         -->

```
  </activity>

  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" android:exported="true"  />
 <!-- Branch init -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="io.branch.sdk.TestMode"
        android:value="true" />
        <!-- Branch install referrer tracking (optional) -->
    <receiver
        android:name="io.branch.referral.InstallListener"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
      <!-- Add this SplashActivity -->
    <activity
    android:exported="true" 
      android:name=".SplashActivity"
      android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
      <meta-data
        android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey"
        android:value="key_live_bmGyWtkyPEiSrNxgdZ8hagcpzDihXAce" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey.test"
        android:value="key_test_aaIB3ukyJCnNsRAfi92SCcdfstmcYAkD" />
    <meta-data  android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@mipmap/ic_notification" />

     <meta-data
 android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
 android:value="AfevrvrtvtrtalGoZo5n3YDI"/>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!!

Comment: add manifest file code for better understanding. An only error cannot solve the problem

Comment: Please add a [mcve] showing your `<receiver>` element for `com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver`. Or, better yet, make sure you are up to date on your Play Services libraries, as [that receiver was removed nearly two years ago](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#analytics_v18-0-0).

Comment: Open your manifest file, at bottom you can find two option, Text and Merged Manifest, In the Merged Manifest, You can also find some tags that need to declare with intent filter, you can edit by that way.

Comment: @KishanMevada i have attached the screenshot can you please guild more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could happen because one or more of your dependencies is missing the `android:exported` tag in any of those elements. I actually experienced this issue a couple of days ago and had to upgrade a couple of them.

What you can do to find out is:

- Target any Android version < 12; one that does not require the tag.
- Build your app.
- Inspect your `AndroidManifest` with Android studio.
- Press a button at the bottom left that reads something about "merged manifests".
- This will show you the merged android manifest for your entire project, including dependencies'.
- Inspect it and figure out which dependency does not conform to Android 12+ requirements.
- Upgrade or patch any of them.

Comment: I have attched the screenshot. Can you please tell in which file you are seeing the issue?

Comment: @User511 As I said, you need to target an Android version < 13 and then build your app so the AndroidManifest gets generated OK. Then you can go and inspect it like this -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqUct.png (don't mind the red highlights, I just took this image from the internet)

Answer (score 0):

It will be enough to check the parts that do not have exported values ​​in the Merge view. Relevant parts of android manifest. You can add it to xml file. But don't forget to give exported value.